# How to Read some of the properties of the ItemSource when Laying out the Children?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Assume that I have the ItemSource bound and i am getting the data. Now what I want is this. The ItemSource will contain Data that tells where each button should be. For Example: The first Button could be at Left:200,Top:0, the Second could be Left:50 Top:20.

```
</ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Controls:MatrixCanvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <item:CustomButton
                    Height="{Binding btnSize}" 
                    Width="{Binding btnSize}" 
                    Style="{Binding bbColor,Converter={StaticResource ButtonStyleConverter}}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>



protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                //The child
            }
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        }
```

The Child however is not giving me access to the Item that I want. Is their a good solution for this? Am I going about this the wrong way? The reason I am doing it like this is because their can be buttons added dynamically, removed, some buttons will need to move around etc..

Comment: What is the item you want?  Do you want the child CustomButton element, does that constitute "the item"?  Or do you want the data item that the child element represents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found  a way to do it.

var presenter = (ContentPresenter)child;
            var dataContext = presenter.DataContext as MyClass;